# Mongodb - grouping several fields using aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents

```js
{name: 'apple',        type: 'fruit',  color: 'red'}
{name: 'banana',       type: 'fruit',  color: 'yellow'}
{name: 'orange',       type: 'fruit',  color: 'orange'}
{name: 'eggplant',     type: 'vege',   color: 'purple'}
{name: 'brocoli',      type: 'vege',   color: 'green'}
{name: 'rose',         type: 'flower', color: 'red'}
{name: 'cauli',        type: 'vege',   color: 'white'}
{name: 'potato',       type: 'vege',   color: 'brown'}
{name: 'onion',        type: 'vege',   color: 'white'}
{name: 'strawberry',   type: 'fruit',  color: 'red'}
{name: 'cashew',       type: 'nut',    color: ''}
{name: 'almond',       type: 'nut',    color: ''}
{name: 'lemon',        type: 'vege',   color: 'yellow'}
{name: 'tomato',       type: 'vege',   color: 'red'}
{name: 'tomato',       type: 'fruit',  color: 'red'}
{name: 'fig',          type: 'fruit',  color: 'pink'}
{name: 'nectarin',     type: 'fruit',  color: 'pink'}
```

I want to group them into alphabets like below

```js
{
 _id:'a',
 name:['apple','almond'],
 type:[],
 color:[]
}

{
 _id:'b',
 name:['banana','brocoli'],
 type:[],
 color:['brown']
}

...

{
 _id:'f',
 name:['fig'],
 type:['fruit','flower'],
 color:['']
}

...

{
 _id:'n',
 name:['nectarin'],
 type:['nut'],
 color:['']
}

...

{
 _id:'p',
 name:['potato'],
 type:[''],
 color:['pink','purple']
}

...
```

The result can be saved into another collection. So I can issue a query in the newly created collection: `find({_id:'a'})` to return name, type and color begins with the letter 'a'.

I have thought about using `$group`

```js
$group: {
  _id: $substr: ['$name', 0, 1],
  name: {$addToSet: '$name'},
}
```

Then another command

```js
$group: {
  _id: $substr: ['$type', 0, 1],
  name: {$addToSet: '$type'},
}
```

And

```js
$group: {
  _id: $substr: ['$color', 0, 1],
  name: {$addToSet: '$color'},
}
```

But I am stuck at how to unify all three together to save into a new collection. Or is aggregation framework not suitable for this kind of data summary?

In a real world example, e.g. a e-commerce site, the front page displays something like: "currently we have `135636` products under `231` categories from `111` brands". Surely, these numbers should be cached somewhere (in memory or in another collection), because running `$group` each time is resource intensive? What would be the optimal schema/design for these situations?

Sorry, my questions are a bit 'confusing'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple arrays here, the key thing is to "merge" them all into one for the simplest processing.

The [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator of the aggregation framework works well here, as well as transforming elements so that you get your "first letter" from each word within the data:

```js
db.alpha.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "list": {
      "$map": { 
        "input": [ "A", "B", "C" ],
        "as": "el",
        "in": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$$el", "A" ] },
            { 
              "type": { "$literal": "name" }, 
              "value": "$name",
              "alpha": { "$substr": [ "$name",0,1 ] } 
            },
            { "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$$el", "B" ] },
              {
                "type": { "$literal": "type" }, 
                "value": "$type",
                "alpha": { "$substr": [ "$type",0,1 ] } 
              },
              {
                "type": { "$literal": "color" }, 
                "value": "$color",
                "alpha": { "$substr": [ "$color",0,1 ] } 
              }
            ]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$list" },
  { "$match": { "list.alpha": { "$ne": "" } } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$list.alpha",
    "list": { 
      "$addToSet": "$list"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": { 
      "$setDifference": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$list",
          "as": "el",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "name" ] },
              "$$el.value",
              false
            ]
          }
        }},
        [false]
      ]
    },
    "type": { 
      "$setDifference": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$list",
          "as": "el",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "type" ] },
              "$$el.value",
              false
            ]
          }
        }},
        [false]
      ]
    },
    "color": { 
      "$setDifference": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$list",
          "as": "el",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "color" ] },
              "$$el.value",
              false
            ]
          }
        }},
        [false]
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

If you look at the data in "stages" it makes a lot of sense what is happening here in the tranformation.

The first stage "maps" all of the fields into a single array per document, so all documents now look like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55df0652c9064ef625d7f36e"),
    "list" : [
            {
                    "type" : "name",
                    "value" : "nectarin",
                    "alpha" : "n"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "type",
                    "value" : "fruit",
                    "alpha" : "f"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "color",
                    "value" : "pink",
                    "alpha" : "p"
            }
    ]
}
```

The [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is of little consequence, as it does the standard and creates new documents from each member. It is the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) that does most of the work here with this result per "alpha" in the grouping:

```js
{
    "_id" : "o",
    "list" : [
            {
                    "type" : "name",
                    "value" : "orange",
                    "alpha" : "o"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "color",
                    "value" : "orange",
                    "alpha" : "o"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "name",
                    "value" : "onion",
                    "alpha" : "o"
            }
    ]
}
```

That has a nice grouping, and is arguably a decent output format. But in order to get to the end results then the `$map` operator is employed again alongside [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) which can be used to remove the `false` values where each field "type" conversion does not match the required output field.

The full result is:

```js
{ "_id" : "a", "name" : [ "almond", "apple" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "b", "name" : [ "brocoli", "banana" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ "brown" ] }
{ "_id" : "c", "name" : [ "cashew", "cauli" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "e", "name" : [ "eggplant" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "f", "name" : [ "fig" ], "type" : [ "flower", "fruit" ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "g", "name" : [ ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ "green" ] }
{ "_id" : "l", "name" : [ "lemon" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "n", "name" : [ "nectarin" ], "type" : [ "nut" ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "o", "name" : [ "onion", "orange" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ "orange" ] }
{ "_id" : "p", "name" : [ "potato" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ "pink", "purple" ] }
{ "_id" : "r", "name" : [ "rose" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ "red" ] }
{ "_id" : "s", "name" : [ "strawberry" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "t", "name" : [ "tomato" ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "v", "name" : [ ], "type" : [ "vege" ], "color" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "w", "name" : [ ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ "white" ] }
{ "_id" : "y", "name" : [ ], "type" : [ ], "color" : [ "yellow" ] }
```

Where everything is grouped alphabetically and with their own arrays for each field.

Upcoming releases of MongoDB will have a `$filter` that makes the `$map` and `$setDifference` combination a bit nicer. But that does not make "sets", not that it matters much to this process as long as [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) is employed where it is.

---

Thinking about this, I would like to "advise" that considering the amount of data you want to process here that the resulting "arrays" for each letter might just possibly exceed the BSON limits depending on how many distinct "words" there actually are.

In which case the "advice" here would be follow the process right up to and including the `$match`, but then only `$group` afterwards like this:

```js
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
      "alpha": "$list.alpha",
      "type": "$list.type",
      "value": "$list.value",
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
```

It's longer output of course, but will not exceed the BSON limit for documents at any stage.

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregation you should use some complex aggregation query. First find out all `name` first letters using `substr` after that create all `name,type and color` array using `group` use **[$map](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** to check whether given name starts with or not 
**[$setDifference](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** used to remove duplicate empty parameter and finally **[$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** used for writing documents in new collection.

Check this aggregation query :

```
    db.collection.aggregate({
    "$project": {
        "firstName": {
            "$substr": ["$name", 0, 1]
        },
        "name": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "color": 1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "allName": {
            "$push": "$name"
        },
        "allType": {
            "$push": "$type"
        },
        "allColor": {
            "$push": "$color"
        },
        "allfirstName": {
            "$push": "$firstName"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$allfirstName"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$allfirstName",
        "allType": {
            "$first": "$allType"
        },
        "allName": {
            "$first": "$allName"
        },
        "allColor": {
            "$first": "$allColor"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "type": {
            "$setDifference": [{
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$allType",
                        "as": "type",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": {
                                    "$eq": [{
                                        "$substr": ["$$type", 0, 1]
                                    }, "$_id"]
                                },
                                "then": "$$type",
                                "else": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                [""]
            ]
        },
        "color": {
            "$setDifference": [{
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$allColor",
                        "as": "color",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": {
                                    "$eq": [{
                                        "$substr": ["$$color", 0, 1]
                                    }, "$_id"]
                                },
                                "then": "$$color",
                                "else": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                [""]
            ]
        },
        "name": {
            "$setDifference": [{
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$allName",
                        "as": "name",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": {
                                    "$eq": [{
                                        "$substr": ["$$name", 0, 1]
                                    }, "$_id"]
                                },
                                "then": "$$name",
                                "else": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                [""]
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "_id": 1
    }
}, {
    "$out": "newCollection"
})
```

Comment: Not sure why you would bother with `$out` considering there can only be 26 documents. If the actual terms were going to cause a problem then the BSON limit would be exceeded on the arrays required for output. Which is a really good reason to avoid grouping by `null` and stuffing the collection into one document.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks for pointing this issue next time will take care.

Comment: I only mention it because of the way you contruct each stage here, and mostly with the early `$group` on `null` should work on this data ( I think so, have not tried but it looks like it ), but it will certainly fail on the size of data the OP is talking about. That was the important part of the question that I saw. And thus, actually a pretty good question as it's not an easy problem to approach.